# Is there anything missable in the HotS campaign?

Tags: starcraft-2

Are there any achievements, side missions, easter eggs, or anything of that sort that I have to get while playing through the campaign, that I can't get by replaying missions after I've completed them?

I would assume achievements like Rally the Troops would be missable, since you have to speak to people before doing something.

But more than achievements, are there any hidden levels or jokes, things that you have to do something specific at a certain time or you'll miss them?

Spoilers as appropriate!

Comment: I don't think the spoiler tag could be used to answer this. basically all the answers are gonna be huge spoilers.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If there was a bonus mission, you could say, make sure you talk to all your advisors before X mission for instance.  I don't think easter eggs need spoilers though.

Comment: You don't, but some do. This is why I made the reference that all answers to this question would have spoilers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### General advice

- Talk with everybody on your **Leviathan** beetween missions! Check it twice.
- Click few times at **Kerrigan** and other **heroes** to hear funny dialogue.
- **Earn** and **play** all **evolution** **missions**. Check it twice! You can miss it.
- Make all additonal tasks in missions to hear dialogues.
- Don't end missions too fast to make all dialogues happen ;)

### Easter eggs list

- Find [Dehaka's right arm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108870/what-is-the-purpose-of-dehakas-right-arm) that is "*Still bleeding profusely*" in "**Supreme**" and him [running in brushes](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/6891640684) in "**Walking The Ancient**"
- Discover that 2 [primal **zerg leaders in Zerus**](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8vesjy) are [Tasteless](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Tasteless) a.k.a *Tastelopes* vs [Artosis](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Artosis) a.k.a *Artosilopes* - pro SC2 players.
- Find out that Blizzard also likes **Minecraft** with [exploding green loctus named Creepers](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8vcqjz) in final Zerus mission.
- When playing as a **Hyperion** your **fighters** will say [Star Wars](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8vduh7) and [Futurama](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8vgzvg) quotes.
- Be a **vandal**! Destroy a shiny new marine car/Helion in the **second Ultralisk evolution** mission and hear him cry about it. Screenshot?
- Say hi to old [Starcraft Brood War](http://www.gamefront.com/starcraft-2-easter-eggs-hidden-references/) **satellite**.
- Find out that Zerglings are [really allergic to **lemon juice**](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8v9wo8) and UNN report from Wings of Liberty was right!
- Hear that there are "[so many **banelings**](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8vcxyl)" like in the [1st GSL Open Finals](http://www.reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/1a9cun/hots_easter_egg_something_i_thought_was_neat/c8viv85).
- In "**Enemy Within**" mission [find **Diablo**](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/starcraft-2/Heart_of_the_Swarm_Secrets)!
- In the **Roach evolution mission** find [Maye, Oynx & Diamond](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/starcraft-2/Heart_of_the_Swarm_Secrets) - this is done for Rebecca Mayes who did [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pX5fNt5QMyI) :D

Comment: Thanks! Hope it will help and be complete list of easter eggs and other missable things in SC2 HotS