# What is the purpose of Dehaka's right arm?

Tags: starcraft-2

In "**Supreme**" mission on **Zerus** planet you can find it

> between first and second champion fight.

I can't do anything with it.

> [image: How it looks]

Are there any possible interaction with this easter egg?

Comment: Combine it with a drone of town portal? Moo? Moo!

Comment: I can't upvote this enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to him about it?

Except from that, I don't think it would do anything, it is only that, an easter egg. Nice find though.

Comment: Now when I think about this I remember that Kerrigan asked about his arm - that he don't need it or something - but I don't remember it.

Comment: yeah, I remember something about that.

Answer (score 2):

The right arm is a part of a Easter Egg for the mission before it.

> [What's up with the Strange Organism in Waking the Ancient?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108940/whats-up-with-the-strange-organism-in-waking-the-ancient)
>  
>  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCLCO.jpg]
>
>  Note how its right arm is missing.

Answer (score -1):

On your first playthrough, if you find it, always talk to Dehaka last when aboard the leviathan after talking to everyone else. Once you beat the campaign, replay the "Supreme" mission on hard and get all the achievements. You will unlock a secret achievement called "Dehaka's Ghost Fist" and a new evolution mission becomes available for evolving the Leviathan's genetic chambers which basically plays like Robotron but with increasingly difficult waves of corrupted Protoss and Terran units.

Comment: Do you have even a single screenshot to suggest that this isn't just an Urban Legend of Zelda? http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UrbanLegendOfZelda