# What's up with the Strange Organism in Waking the Ancient?

Tags: starcraft-2

In the mission Waking the Ancient, around the middle north of the map, there's a neutral critter that burrows as soon as you get anywhere near it. It's definitely selectable; the cursor changed when I moused over it, and I think its name was "Strange Organism" or something like that.

What is it for? Is there a related achievement? Is it maybe part of an Easter egg? Or is it just a red herring?

Please spoiler your answers as appropriate.

Comment: Oooh... selectable? If I remember right, you can nuke selectable neutral critters through mass clicking.

Comment: @Sconibulus: Like I said, it burrows in a hurry once you can see it, so I doubt you click on it enough to nuke it before it gets away.

Comment: I don't believe it's selectable, it just has a tooltip appear when you move the cursor over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is

> Dehaka

skulking around the edges, checking you out for future activities.

---

You can also see him on a ledge above your base in the next mission, The Crucible. [Notice the missing right arm.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108870/what-is-the-purpose-of-dehakas-right-arm)

> [image: Dehaka]

Comment: Note the [right arm](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108870/33619) in the next mission :)