# In the roach evolution mission what do the multicolored crystals paired with the units Maye, Oynx, and Diamond reference?

Tags: starcraft-2

When I reached the area pictured below a scripted event starts showing a girl unit named Maye chased by two creatures named Onyx and Diamond. Between the multi-colored crystals and the named units Blizzard seems to be referencing something here. However, I have no idea what.

What is being referenced in the second part of the “Evolution Mission” for Roaches?

[image: multi-colored crystals and Maye, Oynx, and Diamond unit]

Comment: Not sure how this is supposed to be a duplicate of anything. Leaving open.

Answer (score 5):

In the answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108799/is-there-anything-missable-in-the-hots-campaign) it says it's a reference to a video by Rebecca Mayes:

Comment: A YouTube comment on the video you posted seems to suggest that it is not about Rebecca Mayes. *Stephen kohl*: "After a significant amount of research I concluded this indeed IS NOT the Maye from the SC2 Easter Egg. Maye, Onyx, and Diamond are actually a tribute to a deceased  Blizzard employee and her two favorite dogs. She was the SC cinematic editor (btw thanks, great job!). I think its kinda cool that Blizzard would immortalize a beloved enthusiasts. Certainly wouldn't be the first time, I believe a child player who died of cancer was given an in game shrine in WOW."